# Singleton design pattern for MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, connection, singleton, mongodb-.net-driver

I Implemented Singleton design pattern for my .net mvc web application. The purpose was to hold single connection open throughout the runtime and use that connection for all my requests. But the concurrent requests are opening 1/5 connection even after the Implementation. Am I doing it wrong please share your insights about how I can make this run better ? any small help is good. I am new to this.

**MongoDBMyTableInstance.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using Orniz.OE.BusinessObjects;

namespace OE.Implementations
{
    //Mark the class as 'sealed' so as not to make this class inheritable. Optional.
    public sealed class MongoDBMyTableInstance
    {
        //volatile: ensure that assignment to the instance variable
        //is completed before the instance variable can be accessed
        private static volatile MongoDBOnlineDetailsInstance instance;
        private static object syncLock = new object();

        private static IMongoCollection<MyTable> db = null;

        public static string DBName = DBConnection.MongoDBMyTableExamdatabase;
        public static string connectionString = DBConnection.MongoDBMyTableConnectionString;
        private MongoDBMyTableInstance()
        {
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            db = client.GetDatabase(DBName).GetCollection<MyTable>("MyTable");

        }

        public static IMongoCollection<MyTable> GetMongoCollection
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (syncLock)
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                            instance = new MongoDBMyTableInstance();
                    }
                }

                return db;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**mymethodclass.cs**

```
public static IMongoCollection<MyTable> mytable= MongoDBMyTableInstance.GetMongoCollection;
    public bool TableInsert(MyTable data)
    {
        try
        {
            mytable.InsertOne(data);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Making singletons with "Database" connection is wrong. The connection is always open and you have connection problems. If you use webapis, insert it with liftime.Scoped, elsewhere create a connection when you need it.

Comment: my app is build with .net web not core. where can I use the scoped method you mentioned also I have already tried creating my connection on needby basis but its not working @Den

Comment: Dependency Injection is not integrated in asp.net, you need to add a nuget package. (ninject is one of many)

Comment: 'single connection open throughout the runtime' - I think you want to have a single mongoClient. Used connection is fully different thing

Comment: yep how can I achieve that ? @dododo

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: `my app is build with .net web not core.` then as it was mentioned above, you should just configure DI manually, there are many ways for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection